# How to use PayPal Express Checkout using PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to setup a checkout system on a site using PayPal's PHP SDK, but I am having trouble finding any decent explanations on how to implement it. I am trying to follow the  [SDK usage instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), but it is not particularly clear.

I have generated PayPal API credentials (username, password, signature), but if I understand correctly I also need a "client ID" and "client secret". Is this right? If so, how do I generate them?

Basically, PayPal seem to have awful examples and explanations. I would really like to see an example of how to actually use the SDK for express checkout. If anyone knows any good links or has some code they are willing to post, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend [taking a look at my library instead](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  It makes it a lot easier, and you can also [refer to this demo/sample site](http://paypalphp.angelleye.com/) for a very clear review of how to setup Express Checkout.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented Paypal Express checkout before and its one of simple Payment system from PAYPAL.

**1) you can find Client Id and Client Secret by following the instructions below**

- Login into Paypal developer website(if you intent to use sandbox for testing)
- Goto dashboard
- Click account
- If you sign up with Paypal they will generate two email account(facilitator and buyer by default)
- click on any email account and you should see profile link and notification link
- click profile link
- In API credentials tab you will find Client Id and secret key

I strongly recommend you to use Adaptive payments because it has more flexibility 
follow this link [Adaptive payments](http://www.thecrowned.org/tutorial-paypal-adaptive-payments-api-embedded)

I found this link useful [PHP-EXPRESS CHECKOUT](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/07/paypal-expresscheckout-with-php)

Hope this is useful to you !